# How to highlight keywords in MySQL search results

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a simple way to highlight the searched keywords in the results? The project is a blog. The search function works great, but I would like to highlight the words the search finds.

Here's my code:

```
/*-------------------------  Search    -------------------------------*/  
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'search'){

    // Connect to database
    include 'includes/dbconnect.php';

    // Check if input box is empty
    if( empty($_GET['search_query']) ){

        $errMsg = 'Please enter data to search.';
        include 'includes/error.html.php';
        exit();       
    } 
    else { 

        // Sanitize user data
        $search = htmlspecialchars($_GET['search_query']);

        // Store $search content into $_SESSIONS['search'] for use below
        $_SESSION['search'] = $search;

    }  

    try {
        $sql = "SELECT post_id, post_category_id, post_title, post_date, post_author, post_keywords, post_image, post_content, cat_title
                FROM posts
                INNER JOIN categories
                ON post_category_id = cat_id
                WHERE post_content LIKE '%$search%'
                OR post_title LIKE '%$search%'
                OR post_author LIKE '%$search%'
                OR post_keywords LIKE '%$search'"; 

        $s = $db->prepare($sql);
        $s->execute();
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $errMsg = 'Error fetching data' . $e->getMessage();
        include 'includes/error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

     if($s->rowCount() < 1){
            $errMsg = 'Sorry, no match found for: ' . $_SESSION['search'];
            include 'includes/error.html.php';
            exit();
    } else {

        if($s->rowCount() > 0){
            while($row = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $posts[] = array(
                    'post_id' => $row['post_id'],  
                    'post_category_id' => $row['post_category_id'],
                    'post_title' => $row['post_title'],
                    'post_date' => $row['post_date'],
                    'post_author' => $row['post_author'],
                    'post_keywords' => $row['post_keywords'],
                    'post_image' => $row['post_image'],
                    'post_content' => substr($row['post_content'], 0,240),  //http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
                    'cat_title' => $row['cat_title'],
                );
            }                
        }
    } 

    // Close database connection
    $db = null;

    include 'results.html.php';
    exit();
}
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Yes, but from the code you posted we cannot see the HTML you are building. Show that code, probably from `results.html.php`

Comment: you should try javascript or something, it seems easier (if your query works) to call a `<script>` tag and add a css class at the elements you want...

Comment: <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
        
<div>
    <a href="index.php?getpost=<?php htmlout($post['post_id']); ?>"><?php htmlout($post['post_title']); ?></a>        
    <img src="admin/uploaded_post_images/<?php htmlout($post['post_image']); ?>">
    Category><?php htmlout($post['cat_title']); ?>
    Posted by><?php htmlout($post['post_author']); ?>
    On <?php htmlout($post['post_date']); ?>
    <?php echo $post['post_content']; ?>
    <a href="index.php?getpost=<?php htmlout($post['post_id']); ?>">  Read more </a>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: I can provide the URL

Comment: @JimB814 Don't put complex code in the comments, edit the question.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it could be edited.

Comment: Yeah, it's sneaky of them to hide the "edit" link right there below the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're creating the output, wrap a `span` with an appropriate class around the search term in each of the results, e.g.

```
echo str_replace($search, "<span class='highlight'>$search</span>", $post['post_content']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. On results.html.php I loop through the $posts array and echo $post['post_content'].  How do I integrate your code? I do not have a variable $post_content. Thanks.

Comment: `$post_content = $post['post_content'];` then my code.

Comment: Here how the content is displayed:                                                        <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
        
<div>  
    <p><?php echo $post['post_content']; ?></p>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: Come on, any competent programmer should be able to see how to adapt my answer to their particular code. But I've updated the answer to show you the exact line.

Comment: I think I see that str_replace is grabbing $search and replacing it with $search wrapped in span tags with formatting instructions. I don't see how to apply this. I tried echo str_replace($search, "<span class='highlight'>$search</span>", $post['post_content']); but get an error for Undefined variable: search.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! Now I feel good, because that's how I interpreted your solution!  No error message with: <?php if(isset($search)) {echo str_replace($search, "<span class='bg-yellow'>$search</span>", $post['post_content']);} else {echo $post['post_content'];} ?>

Answer (score 0):

According your your query, you want to look for the search string in multiple fields, however for efficiency sake, its better to group the specific search area's together like so:

```
$searcharray = [
  $posts['post_title'],
  $posts['post_author'],
  $posts['post_keywords'],
  $posts['post_title']
];
```

Now to look for the data you want to replace, loop over the array and replace the content of it:

```
foreach($posts as $k => $post){ // loop over main array;
  $searcharray = [
    $posts['post_title'],
    $posts['post_author'],
    $posts['post_keywords'],
    $posts['post_title']
  ];

  foreach($searcharray as $key => $val){ // loop over each post found.
    $posts[$k][$key] = str_replace($search, "<em>$search</em>", $val);
  }
}
```

### On a side note:

Depending on the amount of data you fetch from the database this could be a bottle neck. Just so you know. Personally, my favorite way of doing this is let the client do it themselves. Print out the data like normal and insert somewhere an element that contains the search attribute or print it directly to Javascript and execute a regex over specific elements to replace the text for the client. This way the server can do server related stuff instead of taking care of the end-user.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/iamwebdesigner/jQuiteLight), build as a plugin for jQuery and very easy to use

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I had the idea that highlighting would be nice, but it appears perhaps more complex than I have time to figure out.